# Does (supporting) rope tension at angles below 45 degrees, increase under load & how?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string, stress-strain

A (semi) cantilevered object such as a door canopy / porch bolted to the face / lintel area of a wall, often requires rod/rope support at the free end.  The "lightweight" supporting rope or rod is fixed to the wall at around 45 degrees from the horizontal above the "root" (where it is fixed at the wall) of the semi-cantilevered canopy.
With the rope at 45 degrees there is an acceptable equilibrium where all the applicable forces are within a range where fittings usually won't break.
But, if the rope fixing is moved down the wall, nearer to horizontal, i.e. less than 45 degrees, eventually the weight of the free end of the "cantilever" overcomes the ropes supporting capacity. How is this calculated? Is there a graph showing the rise in these forces as the rope angle decreases to horizontal? It seems to me they might rise exponentially below 45 degrees, possibly some break point occurs at say 30 degrees (?) where they become potentially catastrophic for the structure. I don't have the mathematics to answer this for myself!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical component of force from the rope needs to support the cantilever.  If you had the rope hanging vertically, the tension in the rope would exactly equal the weight.  The drawback is that a vertical rope needs something to attach to that might not be present, or be annoyingly far away.

As the attachment point moves down to an angle, the vertical component becomes a smaller percentage of the whole.  The tension in the rope has to increase to keep the vertical component constant.

If we think of $\theta$ being the angle from the vertical, then the tension in the rope can be described as

$$ T = \frac{W}{\cos({\theta})} $$

As the angle approaches horizontal, the $\cos (\theta)$ term tends to zero.  The required tension to support the weight near horizontal grows without bound.

The rise is not an exponential, but has a sharp increase that is similar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you BowlOfRed, that is exactly what I was looking for. I could find no useful reference to this particular problem elsewhere. If I read your chart correctly, at 60° from vertical all the forces on wall or cantilever fixings have doubled, by 70° they have tripled & beyond that are rapidly heading towards potential failure of structure, unless some other solution is used, e.g. full cantilever.

Answer (score 0):

Do a free body diagram to find the tension as a function of the weight and the support wire angle.

For example

[image: fig1]

and the balance of forces/torques

$$ \begin{aligned}
  H - T \cos \theta & = 0 \\
  P + T \sin \theta - W & = 0 \\
  T  (L \sin \theta) - W\, \tfrac{L}{2} & = 0
\end{aligned} $$

To be solved for $H$, $P$ and $T$.

This way you will know exactly how the tension $T$ is calculated and how it relates to the angle $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks JAlex, the drawing was no prob, I just couldn't find how the calcs were done for this particular problem. When I have some time I'll try the calc myself.